# Is there any risk of being garbage collected using an unreferenced object

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

Sometimes I dont want to write a new line to declare a Regex object so I write the following code

```
MatchCollection matchCollection = new Regex("example").Matches(someText);
```

With my limited knowledge, I think new Regex("example") might be garbage collected before the Matches start but it is nearly not possible as the operation is so fast.

Am I wrong? Is this kind of coding a bad practice that I should avoid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It is not possible that the object gets GC'ed before it is actually used.

In fact it is (almost) the same as:

```
var r = new Regex("example");
MatchCollection matchCollection = r.Matches(someText);
```

As a proof: here is the IL from an console application containing the code above (1), and a oneliner (2):

Seperate variables:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       27 (0x1b)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] string someText,
           [1] class [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex r,
           [2] class [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection matchCollection)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldstr      "s"
  IL_0006:  stloc.0
  IL_0007:  ldstr      "example"
  IL_000c:  newobj     instance void [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex::.ctor(string)
  IL_0011:  stloc.1
  IL_0012:  ldloc.1
  IL_0013:  ldloc.0
  IL_0014:  callvirt   instance class [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex::Matches(string)
  IL_0019:  stloc.2
  IL_001a:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

Oneliner:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       25 (0x19)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] string someText,
           [1] class [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection matchCollection)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldstr      "s"
  IL_0006:  stloc.0
  IL_0007:  ldstr      "example"
  IL_000c:  newobj     instance void [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex::.ctor(string)
  IL_0011:  ldloc.0
  IL_0012:  call       instance class [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex::Matches(string)
  IL_0017:  stloc.1
  IL_0018:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

You will see that the actual code is not the same. The pushes and pops one variable more from the stack, and the actual call is a little different, but that's all there is. They still call the same object, only the place where it exists is different.

Comment: I dont expect such a detailed answer. Thank you for teaching me the way to investigate myself!